# Google Translate API outputs HTML entities

Tags: google-translate

ENGLISH:
`Sale ID prefix is a required field`

FRENCH:
`Vente préfixe d&#39;ID est un champ obligatoire`

Is there a way to have google translate NOT output the html entity and instead output the actual character (')

CODE: (SEE `translateTo`)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$languages = array('english' => 'en', 'spanish' => 'es', 'indonesia' => 'id', 'french' => 'fr', 'italian' => 'it', 'dutch' => 'nl', 'portugues' => 'pt', 'arabic' => 'ar');

fwrite(STDOUT, "Please enter file: ");
$file = trim(fgets(STDIN));

//Run until user kills it
while(true)
{
    fwrite(STDOUT, "Please enter key: ");
    $key = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    fwrite(STDOUT, "Please enter english value: ");
    $value = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    foreach($languages as $folder=>$code)
    {
        $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../application/language/'.$folder.'/'.$file;
        $transaltedValue = translateTo($value, $code);

        $current_file_contents = file_get_contents($path); 

        //If we have already translated, update it
        if (preg_match("/['\"]{1}${key}['\"]{1}/",$current_file_contents))
        {
            $find_existing_translation = "/(\[['\"]{1})(${key}['\"]{1}[^=]+=[ ]*['\"]{1})([^'\"]+)(['\"]{1};)/";
            $new_file_contents = preg_replace($find_existing_translation, '${1}${2}'.$transaltedValue.'${4}', $current_file_contents);
            file_put_contents($path, $new_file_contents);
        }
        else //We haven't translated: Add
        {
            $pair = "\$lang['$key'] = '$transaltedValue';";
            file_put_contents($path, str_replace('?>', "$pair\n?>", $current_file_contents));
        }
    }


    fwrite(STDOUT, "Quit? (y/n): ");
    $quit = strtolower(trim(fgets(STDIN)));

    if ($quit == 'y' || $quit == 'yes')
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

function translateTo($value, $language_key)
{
    if ($language_key == 'en')
    {
        return $value;
    }

    $api_key = 'MY_API_KEY';
    $value = urlencode($value);

    $url ="https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=$api_key&q=$value&source=en&target=$language_key";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($body);

    return $json->data->translations[0]->translatedText;
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the format as text? According to the [API document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#query-params) this defaults to HTML. I understand that this is used to specify the format of the text that is **to be** translated - but it is worth considering that the response will be in the same format as the request

Comment: That did it! please make an answer so I can award you points!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the Google Translate documentation, you can choose which format you will provide the text which is **to be translated** (see `format` in [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate#query-parameters)). The format defaults to `HTML` if not specfied.

You should set this query parameter to `text` to indicate that you are sending plain-text as Google will likely return the translated text in the same format as it is received.

So your PHP code could become:

```php
$baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";
$params ="?key=$api_key&q=$value&source=en&target=$language_key&format=text";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl + $params );
```

Comment: now, query parameters webpage is here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#query-parameters

Comment: I was struggling a bit with this issue on Javascript. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone working in java, there is a format method in Translate.TranslateOption

So right now you might have something translate call like such:

`YourTranslateObject.translate(yourTextToBeTranslated,Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(yourTargetLanguageCode))`

all you need to do is add a third parameter:

`YourTranslateObject.translate(yourTextToBeTranslated,Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(yourTargetLanguageCode), Translate.TranslateOption.format("text"))`

since HTML is default, this will switch it to text.

Answer (score 2):

If you use google translate client lib,
you should pass **format_** in translate method, not format, it is **format_**
below are google translate python api:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you specify format `Text`, content inside HTML tags will be translated as well. Assume your input is:

`This is a <a href="https://example.com/path">link</a>`

then `example` and `path` will be translated as well, which breaks the link.

To avoid this and fix your problem, stick with format `HTML` and unescape the text you received back from google translate. In php you might use [html_entity_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a client library with the v3 service to translate text, you will need to set the `mimeType` to `text/plain`.

Docs - https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#translating_input_strings